# Hande nil values with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, null, swifty-json

I´m using an JSON api to get data and everything is working as it should, but I don´t really like the way I´m handling the result to be safe if it´s `nil`. This is how it looks today:

I get my JSON and then I iterate it and do the following

```
let obj = Obj()

obj.name = json["name"].string ?? ""
obj.age = json["age"].string ?? ""
obj.length = json["length"].string ?? ""
```

So I check if for example `json["name"].string` has a value otherwise I assign it with an empty `""`. Is this the way to do it with SwiftyJSON or is there a cleaner way?

The issue is that sometimes `json["name"].string` has a value but not `json["age"].string` for example.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do before you start writing code is to figure out what you actually want to do if a value isn't present, or if it is null. You apparently decided that you replace all values that are absent with empty strings. That means you lose the ability to distinguish between the two cases. At some point that will cost you.

I'd add methods that can be called as

```
jsonString ("name")
jsonStringOrEmpty ("name")
jsonStringOrEmptyAcceptNull ("name")
```

and so on, using exactly the one that I want to use in each case, and each implemented to give me debugging information when an unexpected input is encountered.